# Retrieve element size in mm (or in non px unit)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm studying browser DOM with Javascript and building a "system" that relies on millimeter units instead of px.
I know how to set element sizes in mm, that works well with

```
element.style.width = "32mm"; for example.
```

**However I am having trouble retrieving the measurements in any other units than in px. Is there a way to do thi**s?

SIDENOTE: Is there no way to define a global default unit system for css? Would be handy to define what units to use once, and then just use plain values for elements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there no way to define a global default unit system for css?

No, there isn't.

> However I am having trouble retrieving the measurements in any other units than in px. Is there a way to do this?

No, there isn't.

A CSS "pixel" [is effectively 1/96th of an inch](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#x40), 0.26mm. So you can get the size in mm by taking the size in pixels and multiplying by 0.26.

**Note**, however, that that's the "reference" size of a pixel. From the link:

> The reference pixel is the visual angle of one pixel on a device with a pixel density of 96dpi and a distance from the reader of an arm's length. For a nominal arm's length of 28 inches, the visual angle is therefore about 0.0213 degrees. For reading at arm's length, 1px thus corresponds to about 0.26 mm (1/96 inch).

Displays have varying densities, but usually map the CSS pixel as though it were 1/96th of an inch.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27111621/157247) to the original question (didn't realize this was a duplicate when I answered; I *should* have) has a wonderfully-direct approach: Define an element in `mm`, and then get its size in pixels, and you know the conversion for that device, in that orientation.