# HtmlToCanvas crops svg

Tags: reactjs, jspdf, html2canvas

Trying to achieve whats done [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-4798tj?file=index.js). Only problem my downloaded pdf has image croped brutally by right:
[image]

I dive into and catch html2canvas method cause the issue not jspdf,

So how can I force change svg to png properly using html2canvas

component:

```
import PrintButton from "../../../components/print/print";

function QrcodeComponent(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <div id={"barcodeCont"}>
        <QRCode level="L" style={{ width: 256 }} value={JSON.stringify({})} />
      </div>
      <PrintButton id="barcodeCont" />
    </>
  );
}
```

PrintButton:

```
import React from "react";
import html2canvas from "html2canvas";
import jsPDF from "jspdf";

const pxToMm = (px) => {
  return Math.floor(px / document.getElementById("myMm").offsetHeight);
};

const PrintButton = ({ id, label }) => (
  <div className="mt2">
    {/*
    Getting pixel height in milimeters:
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650413/pixel-to-mm-equation/27111621#27111621
  */}
    <div id="myMm" style={{ height: "1mm" }} />

    <div
      onClick={() => {
        const input = document.getElementById(id);
        const inputHeightMm = pxToMm(input.offsetHeight);
        const a4WidthMm = 210;
        const a4HeightMm = 297;

        html2canvas(input).then((canvas) => {
          const imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");//here: this image already cropped..
          let pdf = new jsPDF();
          // Document of a4WidthMm wide and inputHeightMm high
          if (inputHeightMm > a4HeightMm) {
            // elongated a4 (system print dialog will handle page breaks)
            pdf = new jsPDF("p", "mm", [inputHeightMm + 161, a4WidthMm]);
          } else {
            // standard a4
            pdf = new jsPDF();
          }
          pdf.addImage(imgData, "PNG", 0, 0);
          pdf.save(`${id}.pdf`);
        });
      }}
    >
      <button type="button" className="btn btn-lime">
        <i className="fa fa-download"></i> Download{" "}
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default PrintButton;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time you're using `React` and you need to use libs that directly manipulate the dom look into using refs... (it's sort of the `react` equivalent of `document.getElementById`) - it gives you a reference to the dom node... You can do something like this:

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import html2canvas from "html2canvas";
import { jsPDF } from "jspdf";
import "./style.css";

export default function App() {
  const captureRef = useRef(null);

  const getScreenshot = async () => {
    const canvas = await html2canvas(captureRef.current);
    const img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    
    const doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.addImage(img, 10, 10);
    doc.save("a4.pdf");
  };

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <div ref={captureRef} className="to-capture">
        <p>
          This enitre <code>div</code> will be captured
        </p>
      </div>
      <button onClick={getScreenshot}>Get Screenshot!</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-w5qb9a?file=src%2FApp.js

More info on refs: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html